# What is the difference between MultiWayIf and classic guards?

Tags: if-statement, haskell

What does `MultiWayIf` extension offer that cannot be done using `|` guards and vice versa?

For instance, one can write same function as

```
f x | x == 0 = -1
    | otherwise = x
```

or

```
f x = if | x == 0 -> -1
         | otherwise -> x
```

I don't see any difference between these two examples beside syntactic sugar used. Are there situations where I should prefer one over another?

Comment: The purpose is to simplify heavily nested `if` expressions, not replace the existing use of function guards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Multiway `if` is not supposed to be used *instead* of function guards. If you can use guards, you should do that. But the multiway `if` can also be used in the middle of an expression, much like `case`, e.g.:

```
f x = "The argument is " ++ 
         if | x > 0 -> "positive"
            | x < 0 -> "negative"
            | otherwise -> "zero"
```

Personally I do find the clarity of this specific example rather questionable, but this is the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a heavily nested `if` statement like

```
if c1 then a1
else if c2 then a2
else if c3 then a3
else if c4 then a4
else if c5 then a5
else a6
```

`MultiWayIf` lets you write this more concisely as

```
if | c1 -> a1
   | c2 -> a2
   | c3 -> a3 
   | c4 -> a4
   | c5 -> a5
   | otherwise -> a6
```

Also, while every `if` expression must provide a value whether the condition is true or false (`if c then a` is not a valid `if` expression, because the `else` is missing), a multi-way `if` doesn't have to be exhaustive; the `otherwise` can be omitted. This is a syntactic relaxation only; an exception will still be raised once the expression is evaluated if none of the conditions are true.

Answer (score 2):

It's really just syntactic convenience, as others have explained. You can translate any multiway `if` into an equivalent `case` expression quite easily.

```
if
  | c1 -> e1
  | c2 -> e2
  ...
```

is precisely equivalent to

```
case () of
  _ | c1 -> e1
    | c2 -> e2
    ...
```

As usual, `()` means "There's nothing to see here" while `_` means "and we're not looking anyway."